# Running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) linux-image-3.13.0-95-generic

Tags: upgrade

```
philip@philip-HP-Tablet-PC-Tx1100:~$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for philip: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for philip: 
root@philip-HP-Tablet-PC-Tx1100:~# apt-get install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-image-generic-lts-trusty : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-95-generic but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
root@philip-HP-Tablet-PC-Tx1100:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-95-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-lts-trusty-doc-3.13.0 linux-lts-trusty-source-3.13.0
  linux-lts-trusty-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed
  linux-image-3.13.0-95-generic
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/52.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 149 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 169674 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-95-generic (from .../linux-image-3.13.0-95-generic_3.13.0-95.142~precise1_i386.deb) ...
This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-95-generic_3.13.0-95.142~precise1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-95-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-95-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-95-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-95-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-95-generic_3.13.0-95.142~precise1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@philip-HP-Tablet-PC-Tx1100:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can not install this kernel because your CPU is not compatible!

```
This kernel does not support a non-PAE CPU.
```

There's nothing you can do except not to install this kernel `linux-image-3.13.0-95-generic` which got backported from Trusty (14.04) or upgrading your CPU hardware.